# could not determine generated file paths for core data code generation the command 1.the command's standard error was

Tags: swift, database, xcode, core-data

Has anyone here had this kind of error please? I put my file in the cloud then uploaded and then this error appeared.

Showing Recent Messages
Could not determine generated file paths for Core Data code generation: The command `(cd '/Users/gastonteku/Downloads/App Final Work/My-Book-with-Widget-and-Search' && /Users/gastonteku/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/momc --dry-run --action generate --swift-version 5.0 --sdkroot /Users/gastonteku/Documents/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneSimulator14.4.sdk --iphonesimulator-deployment-target 14.0 --module Sur_les_Ailes_de_la_Foi '/Users/gastonteku/Downloads/App Final Work/My-Book-with-Widget-and-Search/MyBookDataModel.xcdatamodeld' '/Users/gastonteku/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Sur_les_Ailes_de_la_Foi-ebjletqfnvziddcmkhqszjlfsyep/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Sur les Ailes de la Foi.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Sur les Ailes de la Foi.build/DerivedSources/CoreDataGenerated/MyBookDataModel')` exited with status 1. The command's output was:

/Users/gastonteku/Downloads/App Final Work/My-Book-with-Widget-and-Search/MyBookDataModel.xcdatamodeld:: error: Could not fetch generated file paths: Error, failed to read Core Data data model from /Users/gastonteku/Downloads/App Final Work/My-Book-with-Widget-and-Search/MyBookDataModel.xcdatamodeld/MyBookDataModel.xcdatamodel: unknown model format [0]

I saw this on Stack but I can't apply it to my project, in fact I don't understand.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A0fjP.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UCukq.png)

Comment: What do you mean by *”I put my file in the cloud then uploaded”*? What file? What do you mean by “put…in the cloud”?

Comment: it's okay I change the name of my data base error has gone, but I have other error. Build input file cannot be found...

Comment: That error message is not much to go on. I'd be glad to help but you're not explaining your situation clearly.

Answer (score 0):

*This may not help the OP, as they already stated they moved on, but I just had the same error and managed to solve it, so I'm posting for future readers.*

---

In my case, for no reason that I could discern, opening my `.xcdatamodeld` file in XCode (v15.0.1) would show a text editor instead of the Core Data UI. Then, when I tried to build, I got the same error as the OP (`unknown model format [0]`).

After trying random suggestions from the Internet—to no avail—I created a new Core Data model, verified the it would open in the Core Data editor, closed XCode and opened Finder.

Right-clicking on the new model (`MyModel.xcdatamodeld`) and selecting "Show Package Contents" showed its contents as `MyModel.xcdatamodel` (different name, missing `d` at the end).

In turn, right-clicking on this and selecting "Show Package Contents" again showed a file named `contents`, with the actual XML contents. So far, so good.

When trying the same with my **non**-working model, inside `NonWorkingModel.xcdatamodeld` there was, as expected, `NonWorkingModel.xcdatamodel`, but this was a file, not another package.

To be precise, it was an XML file with the model contents, but it missed the XML declaration on top (i.e. `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`).

I aligned the non working model structure with the other, creating an intermediate folder and moving the XML to a `contents` file inside the intermediate folder, and adding the XML declaration on top, and—magic!—now XCode opened it correctly.

---

**Bottom line**

If something's wrong with your Core Data model, check its structure in Finder and compare it with a brand new model.